# How to connect autoincrement with auto_date_stamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have autoincremment in my google scripts. I would like add script with fixed timestamp. And connect with auto_increment in one time.

I started auto_increment script and next I start insert_timestamp

```
function auto_increment() {

  var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0; //start column
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 340;// start row

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows() - 1;
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows+1, 2);

  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {
    try {
      var id = vals[row][AUTOINC_COLUMN];
      Logger.log(id);Logger.log((""+id).length ===0);
      if ((""+id).length === 0) {
        // Here the columns & rows are 1-indexed
        worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue(row);
      }
    } catch(ex) {
      // Keep calm and carry on
    }
  }
}


function insert_timestamp() { //function onEdit() I cannot because I need fixed date one day
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var tz = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  if( r.getColumn() != 0 ) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, tz, "dd.MM.yyyy");//"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  }
 }
```

When I write on cell "E" scripts insert new ID and timestamp "dd.mm.yyyy" and fixed when I change text in cell "E" date fixed the last.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What's the problem with this script?

Comment: Script cycles when i delete ID from cells script create new date. When i delete two cells script again create ID.

Comment: Your explanation about "Script cycles when..." suggests that these functions are executed as installable triggers; `onEdit` for one, and possibly `onChange` for the other. In any event, you should be using installable triggers to access the [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that are created when the functions execute. For example, the Event objects would enable you to detect if an id was deleted, or if you deleted a row (or two), and enable you to modify the code for that circumstance.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to explain how these functions are run? Have you installed triggers? Please supply as much information as possible.

Comment: Yes, i have installable triggers 'onChange' I will try something else and maybe I will contact you